# How to make a text slider that moves next or previous in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so I've revised the markup/code to make it easier to understand.  Using JavaScript I want to know how to create a text slider that changes a paragraph in html5 either "forwards" or "backwards" on click?

I only want one div to show at a time and the first div (div_1) needs to be visible at the beginning as a default setting. I also want to be able to add more text divs to it in the future. I'm new to JavaScript so I want to keep it as simple as possible.

I've had a go creating it in JavaScript which hasn't worked, I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       .showHide {
            display: none;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var sdivs = [document.getElementById("div_1"), 
                        document.getElementById("div_2"), 
                        document.getElementById("div_3"),
                        document.getElementById("div_4")];

        function openDiv(x) {
            //I need to keep div_1 open as a starting point
            sdivs[0].style.display ="block";
            var j;
            for (var j = 0; j < sdivs.length; j++) {
                if (j === x) {
                    continue;
                    }
                else {
                    sdivs[j].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }     
    </script>
<title>text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onlick="openDiv(1)">forward</a> 
    <a href="#" onlick="openDiv(-1)">backwards</a>     

    <div id="text_holder">
        <div id="div_1" class="showHide">One</div>
        <div id="div_2" class="showHide">Two</div>
        <div id="div_3" class="showHide">Three</div>
        <div id="div_4" class="showHide">Four</div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with multiple elements like this, I've found CSS alone to be insufficient (though its brilliant for modifying simple hover states or whatever). This one method here is pretty simple and specific to this one set of markup (so modify as you see fit). More importantly - its to illustrate how to set up a simple javascript "class" to handle your logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/1z13qb58/

```
// use a module format to keep the DOM tidy
(function($){

// define vars
var _container;
var _blurbs;
var _blurbWidth;  
var _index;
var _clicks;

// initialize app
function init(){
    console.log('init');
    // initialize vars
    _container  = $('#text_holder .inner');
    _blurbs     = $('.blurb');
    _blurbWidth  = $(_blurbs[0]).innerWidth();
    _clicks     = $('.clicks');
    _index      = 0;

    // assign handlers and start
    styles();
    addEventHandlers();
}

// initialize styles
function styles(){
    _container.width(_blurbs.length * _blurbWidth);
}

// catch user interaction
function addEventHandlers(){
    _clicks.on({
        'click': function(el, args){
            captureClicks( $(this).attr('id') );
        }
    });    
}

// iterate _index based on click term
function captureClicks(term){  
    switch(term){
        case 'forwards':
            _index++;
            if(_index > _blurbs.length - 1){
                _index = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 'backwards':
            _index--;
            if(_index < 0){
                 _index = _blurbs.length - 1;   
            }
            break;
    }
    updateView();
}

// update the _container elements left value
function updateView(){
    //_container.animate({
        //'left' : (_index * _blurbWidth) * -1
    //}, 500);

    _container.css('left', ((_index * _blurbWidth) * -1) + 'px');
}

init();

})(jQuery);
```

I'm using jQuery to handle event binding and animation, but, again - there are lots of options (including a combination of vanilla javascript and CSS3 transitions).

I'll note also that this is all html4 and css2 (save your doctype).

Hopefully that helps -

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm a real novice at this and I'm only interested in JavaScript for now. I've spent hours online trying to find a way to make my paragraphs move back and forth with no luck..I'm probably googling the wrong questions who knows. What you created above is cool but i just need the text to change rather than slide.

Comment: Is it possible to remove this question? I just don't want another beginner Googling for javascript answers and ending up down another jQuery dead end.

Comment: To be clear - jQuery is javascript. You seem to be drawing a distinction between them. Event binding with jQuery is a little easier for newbies, though, which is why I used it. That said - the syntax and class structure is completely relevant. If you just want blurbs to update without a slide transition, simply use "CSS" instead of animate (see my update). (And you probably shouldn't call it a "text slider" if you don't want the text to slide :) .

Comment: You can vote to have the post closed, but a better option would be to clarify your question and focus on what you actually want to achieve. Good luck.

Comment: so (How to open different divs by clicking on a single button?)is the closest I've come to finding the question/answer I want here. The only problem is the JavaScript solution doesn't open the divs one at a time.

Comment: Maybe be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish. Plan out your interactions and specify, in detail, what the intended effect is. Going forward, its a really good idea to show some attempts prior to asking a formal question on SO. Even if its way off base, it will help folks understand what you are up to. You mention spending hours on this - so... what have tried?